# Wifi connectivity problem in 16.10 with Driver RTL8723B Wireless LAN

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.10, realtek-wireless

I have [Haier Y11B Tablet-PC](http://www.haier.com/pk/products/pc/Tablet_PC/y11b_ext.shtml)  I have to install Ubuntu in it but my friend told me there is driver problem in Ubuntu with this laptop (He tried it). So I just tried Ubuntu directly from USB and yes It has problem. Then While Installing Ubuntu tried to connect but got same response.

When I try to connect `wifi` it just keeps trying and then nothing happens. It works perfectly fine with Windows. Ubuntu version is `16.10`

Here is driver details from windows. [image]

Here is details with `lsmod` in **Ubuntu**

[image]

Two more results as asked in comments.

[image: lsusb and lspci results]

[image]

I will test it with direct USB if it works fine then will install Ubuntu.

Any luck ?

Comment: Edit to include results for `lsusb` in Ubuntu with the device connected

Comment: updated take a look.

Answer (score 1):

From the usb.id you posted above and from `lsmod`, we see that your device  uses the driver *rtl8xxxu*. When you run a live session from the USB, check to see what driver is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep rtl
```

It is a relatively new driver and, so far, we are unaware of any problems. Of course, it is easy enough to find out for sure. Run the live session for a few days and try it. If it works correctly, then proceed to install Ubuntu.

If you are still having trouble connecting, please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Comment: lsmod | grep 8723  it shows nothing. 
I just tried lsmod in output there was 
rtl8xxxu      126976    0 
mac80211  757760    1 rtl8xxxu

Comment: sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be 
it also do nothing

Comment: We suspect then that yours is not an rtl8723be device. Once we identify your device, I will amend my answer. Please edit your question to add the result of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2 dont works. 
only lspci -nnk gave output, I am updating it.

Comment: I have revised my answer. Please check.

Comment: Any other Linux distribution can solve the problem ?

Comment: Please see my edit above.